# Can't use headset mic on windows 10 (3.5 mm jack)

Tags: windows-10, audio, drivers, microphone, headset

I have headset with micro on it, but windows can't use it for some reason, instead it uses my laptop micro. I have installed linux on the same machine and it has no problems with mic.

I've tried to install different drivers but it didn't work. Everyone just saying to reinstall drivers or check privacy settings for mic, I've done everything out of it but windows still wont pick up my micro. I don't know why and I can't find solution. In 'recording' tab only one mic (no hidden devices).

- laptop: dell inspiron 7576
- OS: windows 10
- Drivers: realtek

Comment: Most problems with mic's on windows 10 are indeed the privacy setting per app. By default on apps, the mic is blocked and you need to grant it permission. Also, you may need to tell windows to "listen" to the mic. There you can also test if the mic is working.

Comment: I know, but it always laptop mic instead of needed.

Comment: ah, so you need to set the default microphone then, similarly on how you can set the default playback device.

Comment: I don't have another microphone available (show hidden devices - enabled). There is only one micro in 'recording' tab.

Comment: First plugin the mic so it shows up, then set it as default.

Comment: It's plugged in. nothing